# HighStock xAxis values separate from series "y" data

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting several series on a single chart, like this: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

All of my series have the exact same X values, so it's simple and efficient for the server to return the data like this:

```
{
    't': [1234567890, 1234567891, 1234567892, 1234567895],
    'y1': [4, 4, 3, 4],
    'y2': [1, 2, 1, 1]
}
```

This is in contrast to the demos, which serve data like this:

```
{
    'y1': [[1234567890, 4], [1234567891, 4], [1234567892, 3], [1234567895, 4]],
    'y2': [[1234567890, 1], [1234567891, 2], [1234567892, 1], [1234567895, 1]]
}
```

I can set `series[0].data = y1` and `series[1].data = y2`, and it works, but how can I then set the X values from `t` in the first example data?  I tried using `xAxis.categories` but it doesn't seem to work with HighStock and more importantly it seems like it wouldn't be treated as a time series if I used regular HighCharts (which I would be willing to use if it helps).

I don't want to make the server send the time data repeatedly for every series.  And it'd be nice not to have to reorient all the data explicitly in the client.

Comment: You need to convert your data to the right format in the preprocessing (after loading data from your server). In other words, call ajax, load data, convert to the right format and init a chart.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Of course I could use the client (browser/JS) to reorient the data, but since the series params are able to take Y-only arrays, I figure there must be some way to also specify an X-only array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of HighCharts 5.0 (mid 2017) there is no way to do this.  You must feed the data as `[x,y]` pairs, or else there is no way to set the `x` values to anything other than an evenly-spaced range or categorical data.